# Comparison of back references in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var x = "SomeText&nbsp;<a href=\"http://g.com\">http://g.com</a>"; 
var y = x.replace(/<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>/igm, ('$2' == '$1')?"t":"f");
```

The comparison is returning false. And y is now "SomeText f".
How do I compare and get "SomeText t" ? Am I missing something in the condition ?

Printing both the back references prints the same string.

```
var y = x.replace(/<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>/igm, '($2)($1)')
```

This prints the same url for both back references.

Answer (score 1):

The only time that JS will do anything special with a string like `$1` or `$2` is if it is part of the resulting string passed as the second argument to `.replace()`.

What you have as `'$2' === '$1'` was saying `if the string "$2" is the same as the string "$1"`, which is clearly always false.

Instead, what you can do is use the `.match()` method to get the various backreferences as an array which you can index into.

Try the following:

```
var x = "SomeText&nbsp;<a href=\"http://g.com\">http://g.com</a>"; 
var regex = /<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>/igm;
var matches = x.match(regex);
var y = x.replace(regex, matches[2] == matches[1]?"t":"f");
```

Comment: Ohh ok.. So assuming that x variable has multiple links along with text, we need to apply regex once with match() to get all the back references, then use a counter and then use replace function..
That helps.. Thank you GregL.

Comment: If you need to get the value of the backreferences for any purpose other than in a replacement string, you will need to use `string.match(regex)` or `regex.exec(string)` to get back the pseudo-array of results, where element `[0]` is the full string matched by the regex, and `[1]` is the match for backreference #1 (if any, null/undefined if it didn't match).

Comment: For any link that has the href attribute and the inside text as the same link, we want to show it in a different pattern. For all other links, we would be using a different pattern. Hence, using the replace function. However, in one shot this looks like its not possible. If we have multiple links in the string, we will not be able to check the equality of the href attribute and the link text for each link and replace with the right format.